# List all Catalogs within a Library

Tags: sas

**As the title says:** Is there a way to display all catalogs within a library like `WORK` using a `PROC` statement (or something similar)?

I tried `PROC catalog` and `PROC datasets memtype=catalog` but none of these seem to offer this option.

I am using `SAS EG` and indeed there is (at least in EG) a GUI way to list them via `TOOLS -> Catalog and Formats Explorer` and then one can browse through the libraries. However, I'd like to use a non-GUI approach and just couldn't find one so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *dictionary.catalogs*, read more you can [here](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/proc/zsqldict.htm). For example, to display catalogs from lib *Work* you can use this `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
title 'Subset of the DICTIONARY.CATALOGS Table';
title2 'Rows with Library Name WORK';
   select * from dictionary.catalogs
      where libname ='WORK';
quit;
```

Comment: Nice, this works, thanks! Are you aware of any native SAS procedures which could achieve the same?

Comment: @user190080 i'll try to remember, but i think that dictionary.catalogs, dictionary.tables etc, is suitable for these purposes and i advise to use it:)

Comment: @user190080 In addition, you can use it in data steps, not only proc sql. It is just example, that i take from source(url in answer). I think it is really flexible solution.

Comment: PROC SQL is a native SAS PROC.  : ) Other PROCS will likely require to use a view of dictionary.catalogs, e.g. `proc print data=sashelp.vcatalg ; where libname ='WORK'; run;`  If you're using a server with lots of libraries defined, the PROC CONTENTS approach mentioned by Richard may run faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the ODS output portion of `Proc CONTENTS` that lists catalog members.  The `data=` option will be `{the libname}._ALL_`

```
ods results off;
ods output contents.members=work.catalogs;
proc contents data=sashelp._all_ mt=catalog;
run;
quit;
ods results on;
```